# Symfony Doctrine - SQL error when saving OneToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm coding an API in Symfony with API Platform and I have an issue when I persist a relation of my object.

I have few entities. Entity Lead can have few LeadJob and for each LeadJob I create a Project. I use a Subscriber to trigger those creations.

Project relation of entity LeadJob :

```php
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Project::class, inversedBy="leadJob", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $project;

public function getProject(): ?Project
{
    return $this->project;
}

public function setProject(?Project $project): self
{
    $this->project = $project;

    return $this;
}
```

LeadJob relation of entity Project :

```php
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=LeadJob::class, mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $leadJob;

public function getLeadJob(): ?LeadJob
{
    return $this->leadJob;
}

public function setLeadJob(?LeadJob $leadJob): self
{
    $this->leadJob = $leadJob;

    // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
    $newProject = null === $leadJob ? null : $this;
    if ($leadJob->getProject() !== $newProject) {
        $leadJob->setProject($newProject);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

And the Subscriber that create the Project :

```php
final class LeadCreateProjectSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    protected EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::postPersist,
            Events::postUpdate,
        ];
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();

        if (!$entity instanceof Lead) {
            return;
        }

        $this->createProject($entity);
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();

        if (!$entity instanceof Lead) {
            return;
        }

        $this->createProject($entity);
    }

    private function createProject(Lead $lead): void
    {
        if (LeadStatusEnum::FINISHED !== $lead->getStatus()) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($lead->getLeadJobs() as $leadJob) {
            $project = (new Project())
                ->setOwner($leadJob->getUser())
                ->addUser($lead->getOwner())
                ->setOrganization($lead->getOrganization())
                ->setContact($lead->getContact())
                ->setName('Lead '.$lead->getSource()->getName())
                ->setJob($leadJob->getJob())
                ->setLeadJob($leadJob) //this line that causes the error
                ->setComment($lead->getDescription());

            $this->entityManager->persist($project);
        }

        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

So, when I trigger the creation of an Project with everything I need, I have this error message thrown from my Subscriber. There is some properties that I didn't notice, this is the raw error message :

```
"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO lead_job (id, deleted_at, created_at,
updated_at, job_id, user_id, lead_id, project_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' 
with params [\"eafb3b13-bc14-4eb8-92e8-cf3acc55719e\", \"2021-07-22
16:54:45\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement \"\" requires 8"
```

The only way that work is to persist the project, flush, set the relation and persist it in the Subscriber. And delete the setLeadJob on the Project object :

```php
$this->entityManager->persist($project);
$this->entityManager->flush();
$leadJob->setProject($project);
$this->entityManager->persist($leadJob);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Why the cascade persist is not doing the job? And why I have this error?

Comment: How do you create a Project? I don't see any code related to API Platform in your question.

Comment: I use the Subscriber to create a Project for each LeadJob in the Lead. I didn't noticied all the api platform code but he's present.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes, I'm still on it, but I have some issue with persisting my entities after the onFlush Event. When I find the answer, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist):

> **postUpdate, postRemove, postPersist**
>
> The three post events are called
> inside `EntityManager#flush()`. Changes in here are not relevant to the
> persistence in the database, but you can use these events to alter
> non-persistable items, like non-mapped fields, logging or even
> associated classes that are not directly mapped by Doctrine.

I think this is not very clear, so in other words: don't persist (other) entities inside a `postPersist` listener. Because `postPersist` happens during the flush event, new persisted entities (like your `Project`) aren't flushed. And flushing during a flush event leads to unexpected behaviour, like the error in your question.

You should use a [`onFlush` event](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#onflush) instead:

```
class FlushExampleListener
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {

            if ($entity instanceof Lead) {
                $this->createProject($entity);
            }
        }
    }
    private function createProject(Lead $lead): void
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```